# удаление части спрайта (кодом) в unity 2d

Tags: unity3d, 2d

пытаюсь сделать разрушение в unity 2d, как в worms

хотел делать удаление части спрайта, но не нашел как это сделать

может есть более хороший способ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте больше информации, чего вы *конкретно* хотите и что уже пробовали для этого. Тогда, возможно, кто-то заметит, где была ваша ошибка. Пока могу сказать - возможно вам нужны методы `GetPixels` и `SetPixels` класса `Texture2D`.

Comment: Я находил эти методы, но не понимаю как получить текстуру спрайта

и мне интересно будет ли данный способ оптимизированным?

Comment: Можно попробовать использовать маску. Что-то "разрушилось" - подредактировали маску на спрайте - и часть спрайта не отображается.
Но с коллайдерами, если они нужны, так не работает...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скидываю пример из своего проекта. Надеюсь, разберетесь.
Прикрепляем скрипт на пустой объект. Ставим туда 256х256 текстуру с включенными чтением/записью. Входной двухмерный массив должен состоять из значений 1 и 0 (есть земля/нет земли).

Здесь компонент `SpriteRenderer` не присутствует изначально, а навешивается при вызове `Init`. Спрайт также создается на лету. Я не уверен, будет ли в ином случае изменение текстуры затрагивать все спрайты на ее основе, скорее всего, да.

Изменения в текстуру вносятся блоками (в игре она очень большая, и обновление ее всей вызывает ощутимую задержку). Вызываем `PrepareBlock`, потом вызываем `SetPixel` для тех пикселей в блоке что мы меняем (`SetPixel` этого скрипта, **не текстуры**), потом `ApplyBlock`.

```
public class LandRenderer : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField] private Texture2D _template;

    private Texture2D _texture;
    private Color []  _tempArray;
    private int       _w, _h;
    private int       _blockX, _blockY, _blockW, _blockH;


    public void Init (byte [,] array) {
        _w = array.GetLength (0);
        _h = array.GetLength (1);

        var template = _template.GetPixels ();

        var result = new Color [_w * _h];
        for (int x = 0; x < _w; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < _h; y++) {
            result [x + y * _w] = array [x, y] == 0
                ? Color.clear
                : template [x % 256 + y % 256 * 256];
            // 256 это размер текстуры
        }

        _texture = new Texture2D (_w, _h, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);
        _texture.wrapMode = TextureWrapMode.Clamp;
        _texture.SetPixels (result);
        _texture.Apply ();

        gameObject.AddComponent <SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = Sprite.Create (
            _texture,
            new Rect (0, 0, _w, _h),
            Vector2.zero,
            1,
            0,
            SpriteMeshType.FullRect
        );
    }


    public void SetPixel (int x, int y, Color color) {
        x -= _blockX;
        y -= _blockY;
        _tempArray [x + y * _blockW] = color;
    }


    public void ApplyBlock () {
        _texture.SetPixels (_blockX, _blockY, _blockW, _blockH, _tempArray);
        _texture.Apply ();
        _tempArray = null;
    }


    public void PrepareBlock (IntBox box) {
        _blockW = box.X1 - (_blockX = box.X0);
        _blockH = box.Y1 - (_blockY = box.Y0);
        _tempArray = _texture.GetPixels (_blockX, _blockY, _blockW, _blockH);
    }

}
```

`IntBox` - просто структура с 4 полями. `X0` - левая граница, которая включается, `X1` - правая, которая не включается. `Y*` по аналогии.